# Dog breed API Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, api

This is the [link to the API for JSON](https://dog.ceo/dog-api/breeds-list).

I am trying to access the list and the image of the dog breeds, but it is displaying nothing when my app starts in Android Studio.

After the Main Activity Class i have given the CustomAdapter Class also. 
Tried with other things but not working.

Here is my MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Product> arrayList;
    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ReadJSON().execute("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all");
            }
        });
    }

    class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask<String,Integer, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return readURL(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String content) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
                JSONArray jsonArray =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("status");

                for(int i =0;i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject productObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    arrayList.add(new Product(
                            productObject.getString("status"),
                            productObject.getString("message")
                    ));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_row, arrayList
            );
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    private static String readURL(String theUrl) {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            // create a url object
            URL url = new URL(theUrl);
            // create a urlconnection object
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            // wrap the urlconnection in a bufferedreader
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            // read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(line + "\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content.toString();
    }
}
```

CustomerAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    ArrayList<Product> products;
    Context context;
    int resource;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Product> products) {
        super(context, resource, products);
        this.products = products;
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null, true);

        }
        Product product = getItem(position);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        Picasso.with(context).load(product.getImage()).into(image);

        TextView breedName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.breedName);
        breedName.setText(product.getBreedName());


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Product:

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made changes to your code as follow:

**UPDATE**: thanks to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50187771/6819114) by @Jay Rathod RJ, I updated the code so it will load Breed Names from the server, then load images as per breed name accordingly.

Create BreedLoader class:

```
package com.example.pbp22.dogbreed;

import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.content.Context;

import java.util.List;

public class BreedLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Breed>> {
/**
 * Tag for log messages
 */
private static final String LOG_TAG = BreedLoader.class.getName();

List<String> breedNames;

public BreedLoader(Context context, List<String> breedNames) {
    super(context);
    this.breedNames = breedNames;
}

@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    forceLoad();
}

/**
 * This is on a background thread.
 */
@Override
public List<Breed> loadInBackground() {

    // Perform the network request, parse the response, and extract a list of breeds.
    return QueryUtils.fetchBreedData(breedNames);
}
}
```

Create BreedNameLoader class:

```
package com.example.pbp22.dogbreed;

import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.content.Context;

import java.util.List;

public class BreedNameLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<String>> {

    /**
     * Tag for log messages
     */
    private static final String LOG_TAG = BreedLoader.class.getName();

    public BreedNameLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        forceLoad();
    }

    /**
     * This is on a background thread.
     */
    @Override
    public List<String> loadInBackground() {

        // Perform the network request, parse the response, and extract a list of earthquakes.
        return QueryUtils.fetchBreedNameData();
    }
}
```

Create QueryUtils class:

```
    package com.example.pbp22.dogbreed;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class QueryUtils {

    /** Tag for the log messages */
    private static final String LOG_TAG = QueryUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Query the dataset and return a list of {@link Breed} objects.
     * @param breedNames
     */
    public static List<Breed> fetchBreedData(List<String> breedNames) {

        // Perform HTTP request to the URL and receive a JSON response back
        List<String> jsonResponse = readImageUrl(breedNames);

        // Extract relevant fields from the JSON response and create a list of {@link Breed}s
        List<Breed> breeds = extractBreedFromJson(jsonResponse, breedNames);

        // Return the list of {@link Breed}s
        return breeds;
    }

    /**
     * Query the dataset and return a list of {@link Breed} objects.
     */
    public static List<String> fetchBreedNameData() {

        // Perform HTTP request to the URL and receive a JSON response back
        String jsonResponse = readBreedNameUrl();

        // Extract relevant fields from the JSON response and create a list of {@link Breed}s
        List<String> breedNames = extractBreedNameFromJson(jsonResponse);

        // Return the list of {@link Breed}s
        return breedNames;
    }

    private static List<String> readImageUrl(List<String> breedNames) {

        List<String> reponses = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String breed : breedNames) {
            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                // create a url object
                URL url = new URL(String.format("https://dog.ceo/api/breed/%s/images/random", breed));
                // create a urlconnection object
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                // wrap the urlconnection in a bufferedreader
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                // read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    content.append(line + "\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            reponses.add(content.toString());
        }

        return reponses;
    }

    /**
     * Return a list of {@link Breed} objects that has been built up from
     * parsing the given JSON response.
     */
    private static List<Breed> extractBreedFromJson(List<String> responses, List<String> breedNames) {

        // If the JSON string is empty or null, then return early.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(responses.toString())) {
            return null;
        }

        // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding breeds to
        List<Breed> breeds = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < responses.size(); i++) {

            try {

                // Create a JSONObject from the JSON response string
                JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(responses.get(i));

                String image = baseJsonResponse.getString("message");

                String breedName = breedNames.get(i);

                breeds.add(new Breed(image, breedName));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
                // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
                // with the message from the exception.
                Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the JSON results", e);
            }


        }

        // Return the list of breeds
        return breeds;
    }

    private static String readBreedNameUrl() {

            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                // create a url object
                URL url = new URL("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all");
                // create a urlconnection object
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                // wrap the urlconnection in a bufferedreader
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                // read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    content.append(line + "\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return content.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Return a list of {@link String} objects (breed names) that has been built up from
     * parsing the given JSON response.
     */
    private static List<String> extractBreedNameFromJson(String responses) {

        // If the JSON string is empty or null, then return early.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(responses)) {
            return null;
        }

        // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding breed names to
        List<String> breedNameList = new ArrayList<>();


            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responses);
                JSONObject messageObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("message");

                for (Iterator<String> iter = messageObj.keys(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
                    String key = iter.next();
                    Log.w("key", key);
                    breedNameList.add(key);
                }

                Log.w("messageObj", messageObj.toString());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
                // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
                // with the message from the exception.
                Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the JSON results", e);
            }

        // Return the list of breeds
        return breedNameList;
    }

}
```

Your adapter class has been changed a tiny bit:

```
package com.example.pbp22.dogbreed;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    List<Product> products;
    Context context;
    int resource;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Product> products) {
        super(context, resource, products);
        this.products = products;
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null, true);

        }
        Product product = getItem(position);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        Picasso.with(context).load(product.getImage()).into(image);

        TextView breedName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.breedName);
        breedName.setText(product.getBreedName());


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

And here is your main activity:

```
    package com.example.pbp22.dogbreed;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    ListView list;

    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<String>> breedNameLoaderCallbacks;
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Breed>> breedLoaderCallbacks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        breedLoaderCallbacks = new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Breed>>() {
            @Override
            public Loader<List<Breed>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {

                List<String> breedNames = null;

                if (bundle != null) {
                    breedNames = new ArrayList<>(bundle.getStringArrayList("breed_name"));
                }

                return new BreedLoader(MainActivity.this, breedNames);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Breed>> loader, List<Breed> products) {


                if (products != null && !products.isEmpty()) {
                    Log.v("DogXXX", products.toString());
                    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(
                            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_row, products
                    );
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Breed>> loader) {

            }
        };

        breedNameLoaderCallbacks = new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public Loader<List<String>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
                return new BreedNameLoader(MainActivity.this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<String>> loader, List<String> strings) {

                Bundle breedNameBundle = new Bundle();
                breedNameBundle.putStringArrayList("breed_name", (ArrayList<String>) strings);
                getLoaderManager().initLoader(2, breedNameBundle, breedLoaderCallbacks);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<String>> loader) {

            }
        };

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, breedNameLoaderCallbacks);
    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: as Picasso needs time to load those images, it takes a while for the images to be loaded.

Comment: Thanks. It was really helpful.

Comment: UPDATE: thanks to the solution by @Jay Rathod RJ, I updated the code so it will load Breed Names from the server, then load images as per breed name accordingly. You can still use the old code, but the new code will load breed names from server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to made changes in your `AsyncTask` method. You need to change *Json Parsing* process as below which you were doing wrong.

Change your `ReadJSON` class as below.

```
class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return readURL(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String content) {
        try {
            Log.w("content", content);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
            JSONObject messageObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("message");

            for (Iterator<String> iter = messageObj.keys(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
                String key = iter.next();
                Log.w("key", key);
                arrayList.add(new Product("", key));
            }

            Log.w("messageObj", messageObj.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(
                TestActivity.this, R.layout.list_row, arrayList
        );
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

I made only displayed breed name currently. **For random `Image` you should get it from the related api based on name.**

Inside `CustomAdapter` i have setup breed names only as of now.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    ArrayList<Product> products;
    Context context;
    int resource;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Product> products) {
        super(context, resource, products);
        this.products = products;
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null, true);

        }
        Product product = getItem(position);

        /*ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivBreedDog);
        Picasso.with(context).load(product.getImage()).into(image);*/

        TextView breedName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.breedName);
        breedName.setText(product.getBreedName());


        return convertView;
    }


}
```

**Product**

```
public class Product {
    // Store the name of the movie
    private String image;
    // Store the release date of the movie
    private String breedName;

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getBreedName() {
        return breedName;
    }

    public void setBreedName(String breedName) {
        this.breedName = breedName;
    }


    // Constructor that is used to create an instance of the Movie object
    public Product(String image, String breedName) {
        this.image = image;
        this.breedName = breedName;
    }
}
```

This will give you the **`breed name`** inside *`list`* only.

Output of **`breed name`** in **`list`**.

[image]

Comment: Thank You. The list is proper.

Comment: What if I have to Display images with the list? and multiple images in the list. like 3 images of the particular breed in a particular list item?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code easy to handle it ..

Add below dependency into app level gradle file.

```
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

then after make retrofit object class like below ..

```
public class ApiClient {
private final static String BASE_URL = "https://dog.ceo/api/breed/";

public static ApiClient apiClient;
private Retrofit retrofit = null;
private Retrofit retrofit2 = null;

public static ApiClient getInstance() {
    if (apiClient == null) {
        apiClient = new ApiClient();
    }
    return apiClient;
}

//private static Retrofit storeRetrofit = null;

public Retrofit getClient() {
    return getClient(null);
}


private Retrofit getClient(final Context context) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    return retrofit;
}
```

}

then make interface to api call like below code..

```
public interface ApiInterface {
  @GET("{catname}/images")
  Call<Product> getProductData(@Path("catname") String breed);
```

}

then in api call in activity like below code ..

```
    public void getProductData() {
    ApiInterface apiInterface=ApiClient.getInstance().getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<Product> productCall=apiInterface.getProductData("airedale"); // pass your string as dog brand.
    productCall.enqueue(new Callback<Product>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Product> call, retrofit2.Response<Product> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body()!=null){
                Product product=response.body();
                productlist.add(product);

                Log.d("Status",product.getStatus());
                Log.d("Message",product.getMessage().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Product> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

make product class like below code..

```
public class Product {

@SerializedName("status")
private String status;
@SerializedName("message")
private List<String> message = null;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public List<String> getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(List<String> message) {
    this.message = message;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return
            "Response{" +
                    "message = '" + message + '\'' +
                    ",status = '" + status + '\'' +
                    "}";
}
```

}

Comment: API you giving is just for one particular breed. What about all the breeds list. and here is my code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LV30WF915P49J0u5kTahrISHZuuCUkTg

Comment: i update my code you can make parameter method and pass into particular value it gives response according.

Comment: Not Working. Showing error for the breeds. Can you run it on your machine and give me the updated one. The rest things are in the drive link.

Comment: App is crashing. Can you send me the code in a drive link.

Comment: I update my code again check it now because I test not crash app and data print into logcat.

Comment: i add one line more to add product data into product list then pass into adapter.

Comment: Please send me the code using Google Drive. In my Android Studio, the app is crashing

Comment: Will you please send the code? My application is crashing. I can use your code to see if it is really working or not

Comment: I give full code to you only make all things are separately I think you add things into one class.